# Panolens - where to get right mouse coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, panoramas

I'm trying to create panoramas with [panolens.js](https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js) and link them together. The link supposed to be in a certain position on the screen. I was trying to use provided  panorama_linking as an example but in firefox I get completely different mouse coordinates from the coordinates in example's html. In example's html the coordinates of infospot (link position) is ( -74.56, -58.83, 31.10 ), but firefox for the same infospot gives me these coordinates - { 3690.64, -2912.02, 1539.42 }. What I'm doing wrong? How to get the right coordinates?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but you have to add the following option when you declare your viewer :

```
viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({output: 'console'});
```